# Append element to outside of div

Tags: html, css, floating

I have divs wherein they are positioned one after another, and they need to be adjacent to each sibling. Simultaneously, there is a button/tab that belongs to this div, and is "welded" to the top of its parent div, like pictured below:

[image]

How would I create this effect, given that my primary goal is to have the (stroked) borders of the div in question serve as the border between sibling elements?

Comment: use absolute positioned pseudo-elements.

Comment: you mean something like .div:before in css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just absolute position the button

```css
div{
  width:200px; height:120px;
  border:2px solid red;
  position:relative;
}

.tab{
  position:absolute;
  height:20px; width:50px;
  top:-20px; right:-2px;
  background:red;
  border:2px solid red;
}

div:nth-child(2){
  border-color:blue;
}
div:nth-child(2) .tab{
  background:blue;
  border-color:blue;
}

/*just to make space in this snippet*/
div:first-child{
  margin-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="tab"/>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="tab"/>
</div>
```

Comment: How would you place an element within the the tab you created there btw

Comment: in my case a button is going to end up there

Comment: @Skyler then use the same technique, only positioning the element instead of a pseudo. I've changed my example, check it back.

Answer (score 0):

to add element to outside of div, you can use jQuery.

you can try this example

```
<style>
  .bg-green {
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    background: #0f0;
    margin: 10px;
  }
</style>
<button onclick="appendElement()">Click To Appent to Outside The Element</button><br><br>
<div id="example" class="bg-green"></div>

<script>
 function appendElement(){
   $('#example').after('<div class="bg-green"></div>')
 }
</script>
```

i hope this can help

Answer (score -1):

You can use z-index for your blue div in the picture that has some value that is greater of the red bordered box and position it to overlap with red div box element. For example for your blue div filled box :

```
.blue-filled-div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px; // replace the values according to red box
    top: 150px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

z-index will give 'depth' to your blue div and place it in front of red box div.

Comment: blue box will be in front / above the red one anyway, just because it appears later in the html structure. No need to z-index.